# How to load data for autosuggest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, autosuggest

I am building a note-taking app where you can add tags to notes. When a user starts adding a new tag, I want to autosuggest the tag from all of its previous saved tags.
How do I implement that?
Do I request for the user's every previously saved notes, get tags and compare them with what the user is typing or do I maintain a collection of tags when the user is adding a note?
What is the correct approach and how do we decide?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a separate collection for tags, with the user id on them.
2. Store user searched tags on local storage, and on the page, load retrieve
   all the tags, and search with it.